# Integration tests with PayPal

Tags: paypal

I would like to be able to test our integration with PayPal.  We have sandbox accounts set up, etc, and I can even create payments.  However, I'd like to be able to also issue refunds, query for refunds, and all the other APIs, all via integration tests and without human or even browser involvement. The difficult part seems to be that, of course, the PayPal flow requires someone to interact with a PayPal URL and approve the purchase.

Some more detail : We use the standard e-commerce flow on our site.  User shows up, puts a product in a cart, proceeds to buy flow, selects a payment method, in this case PayPal.  Of course, in PayPal's case, we create the Payment in PayPal and then simply show the embedded popup of palpal's flow where the user logs into their PayPal account and approves the purchase.  PayPal does all this work.  We simply get the response that 'yes, the purchase has been approved'.

So.. in an integration test environment, we can create the Payment entity in PayPal but.. how do we, in a sandbox environment integration test, get that payment approved?  Is there a developer API available on the sandbox environment that says 'hey, this PayPal user approves this payment' or 'hey, this PayPal user rejects this payment', so that in test code we can simulate the buyer's flow.  Or is there a way to set up a sandbox account to just 'auto approve' purchases or 'auto reject' purchases, simply for a test environment?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do anything in the sandbox that you can do on the live servers.  This is a very broad question, though, so it's tough to answer.

For example, if you want to process payments without the need for any browser flow you'll need to have a billing agreement setup or a Pro transaction so you can run reference transactions.  This would involve Express Checkout APIs and/or Payments Pro APIs, and reference transactions APIs.  Depending on whether you're using Classic or REST, though, the API calls would be different.

In any case, once a transaction exists in the PayPal sandbox system you could then use the API to refund it.  Same thing, though...you'd either be using REST APIs or Classic.

If you can provide more specifics in your question I can update this answer to be more specific as well.

Comment: updated the description.  I'll look into this billing agreement setup, though I don't want the integration test to wander far from how we do things in production.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Still not sure I understand your concern here.  The sandbox is exactly the same as live.  So yes, the API is the same except the endpoint would have sandbox.paypal.com instead of just paypal.com, and you would get the same API response as you would live.

Comment: Yep, and I get that. However, integration tests... just to test our code's responses to PayPal APIs, etc, require that a Payment move from the created state to an approved state... in order to test, for example, refunds.  When I write integration tests against Stripe, for instance, I provide a test-flagged fake credit card number that is always approved (or one that is always rejected).  It seems I simply cannot write those types of integration tests against PayPal.

Comment: Have you looked into PayPal negative testing in the sandbox?  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_error-conditions/